# Can you create a dynamic image changer in React native?

Tags: function, dynamic, react-native, react-native-ios

Can you create a dynamic image changer in React native?

```
const btnRender =(txtButton, ImgUrl)=>{
    let image = '../../assets/icons/objects/dog.png'
    ImgUrl ? image = ImgUrl : '../../assets/icons/objects/dog.png'

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.picContainer}>
            <Image source={require(image)} style={styles.icons}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

{btnRender("test1", '../../assets/icons/objects/cat.png')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically require a file, you need to allocate on memory first, before assigning it:

```
const btnRender =(txtButton, ImgUrl)=>{
    var image = require('../../assets/icons/objects/dog.png');

    if(ImgUrl !== undefined){
      image = ImgUrl;
    }

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.picContainer}>
            <Image source={image} style={styles.icons}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  } 

  btnRender("test1",require("../ThePathOfTheImage"))
```